# Testing availaibility of endpoints

Tags: java, testing, endpoints

I have a property file with a banch of endpoints(SAOP, REST, JMS...) that my application is using. I'm looking for an way to load the property file and be able to test if those endpoints are available.

I can programme it but I was wondring if there is a tool that fullfill this dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

for simple availability just use curl with sample query. wrap it in bash script and let your CI server fires it every x seconds/hours. you can use grep to do simple asserts on the response

to check correctness you have to develop a bit more complex integration tests

Comment: I'm trying to see if there is any solution out there before trying to implement my own. But a script in CI server is a good idea. Thanks